# Conditional compilation in Rust 0.10?

Tags: rust, rust-obsolete

I have been using 0.10 and recently setup a build of nightly to experiment with Box and friends.

Now I have code for 0.10 using `~str` and code for pre0.11 using `String` because of `to_owned` being obsolete. I thought I could do this:

```
#[cfg(rust_version = "0.10")]
fn my_old_func() -> Option<~str> {
}

#[cfg(not(rust_version = "0.10")]
fn my_old_func() -> Option<String> {
}
```

And pass `--cfg rust_version:0.11` during compilation. But the compiler still chokes on the now removed `~` operator. Is there a way to have code that works under both 0.10 and the as yet unreleased 0.11 using conditional compilation or some other mechanism?

I guess I could fall back to using cpp and #ifdef but that seems like stepping out of the Rust mindset.

Comment: Btw, I think you would have to pass `--cfg 'rust_version="0.11"'` for the `cfg` to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, there is nothing you can do about this.

Our typical recommendation is not to use 0.10 but to stick with nightlies.

Comment: To expand, This is because the parser isn't a completely different step, like the C++ preprocessor is.