# Example of how to use Conditional Compilation Macros in Rust

Tags: rust

I've followed [quite a bit](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/attributes.html#conditional-compilation) of [the documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html) and tried to [reuse an example](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/conditional-compilation.html), but I can't get my code to work.

My Cargo.toml looks like this:

```
[package]
name = "Blahblah"
version = "0.3.0"
authors = ["ergh <derngummit@ahwell.com"]
[dependencies]

[[bin]]
name = "target"
path = "src/main.rs"

[features]
default=["mmap_enabled"]
no_mmap=[]
mmap_enabled=[]
```

I'd like to test my code locally with a different buffer origin than mmap based on what feature configuration I pass to the `cargo build` command. I have this in my code:

```
if cfg!(mmap_enabled) {
    println!("mmap_enabled bro!");
    ...
}
if cfg!(no_mmap) {
    println!("now it's not");
    ...
}
```

The compiler doesn't see the code in either of the `if` statement bodies, so   I know that both of the `cfg!` statements are evaluating to false. Why?

I've read [Conditional compilation in Rust 0.10?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24297154/conditional-compilation-in-rust/) and I know it's not an exact duplicate because I'm looking for a functioning example.

Comment: Incidentally, mutually exclusive features should be done with a single feature rather than two independent ones e.g. test `feature = "mmap"` and `not(feature = "mmap")`. Specifically, a user of the crate can enable both `no_mmap` and `mmap_enabled`, which seems like it may be problematic.

Comment: I had thought about that, and 1) the package is internal and 2) the code is exclusive, in the sense that one is not evaluated if the other is.

Comment: Cool! Sounds like you've got it all under control. (Was just making sure you knew of the trade-offs.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The correct way to test for a feature is `feature = "name"`, as you can see in [the documentation you linked](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/first-edition/conditional-compilation.html) if you scroll a bit:

> As for how to enable or disable these switches, if you’re using Cargo,
>   they get set in the [`[features]` section](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html#the-features-section) of your `Cargo.toml`:
>
> ```
> [features]
> # no features by default
> default = []
>
> # Add feature "foo" here, then you can use it. 
> # Our "foo" feature depends on nothing else.
> foo = []
> ```
>
> When you do this, Cargo passes along a flag to `rustc`:
>
> ```
> --cfg feature="${feature_name}"
> ```
>
> The sum of these `cfg` flags will determine which ones get activated,
>   and therefore, which code gets compiled. Let’s take this code:
>
> ```
> #[cfg(feature = "foo")]
> mod foo {
> }
> ```

In your case using the `cfg!` macro, this would map to `cfg!(feature = "foo")`.

Comment: That's how you include or disclude an entire module. But I have a small body of code that must be exchanged in the middle of a function. So that syntax and definition won't work.

Comment: I understand. What I'm highlighting here is the syntax of how to test for a _feature_, i.e. the thing inside the cfg. It should be `feature = "name"`, not just `cfg(name)`.

Comment: I literally was writing an answer to my own question when you wrote that response that included that. You pointed out the correct way to do it.