# Rust conditional compilation(cfg) with single identifier

Tags: rust

I'm trying to understand the following example from the [condition compilation manual @ doc.rust-lang.org](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html):

```rust
// This function is only included when either foo or bar is defined
#[cfg(any(foo, bar))]
fn needs_foo_or_bar() {
  // ...
}
```

What do those `foo` and `bar` identifiers represent?

Is this a shortcut for `target_os` identifiers or what is it for?

Comment: Unfortunately you have to scroll down a bit to actually find some usable examples of what can take the places of `foo` and `bar`: https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#forms-of-conditional-compilation

Answer (score 1):

Turns out it had nothing to do with `target_os`, it is what you set in `RUSTFLAGS` when you build/run:

> RUSTFLAGS='--cfg foo'

> Which configuration options are set is determined statically during the compilation of the crate. Certain options are compiler-set based on data about the compilation. Other **options are arbitrarily-set**, set based on input passed to the compiler outside of the code.

[Related question with a bit more advanced example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338478/how-to-set-cfg-options-to-compile-conditionally)

Answer (score 0):

From the syntax definition on the [conditional compilation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#conditional-compilation) manual, `any(foo, bar)` is a `ConfigurationPredicate` (specifically the `ConfigurationAny` variation) so `foo, bar` is a `ConfigurationPredicateList` and thus `foo` and `bar` are each a `ConfigurationPredicate`. So you could use them to conditionally compile for a target OS. Or you could do some custom features like this:

```
#[cfg(any(feature = "myfeature1", feature = "myfeature2"))]
pub struct Source {
    pub email: String,
    pub name: String,
}
```

For more on custom features, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27632660/how-do-i-use-conditional-compilation-with-cfg-and-cargo)