# Rust: How do I actually enable `#[cfg(no_global_oom_handling)]`?

Tags: rust

So, laced throughout `alloc` and `std` methods are marked with `#[cfg(not(no_global_oom_handling))]`, primarily methods that perform allocations where the case of running out of memory is handled via panicking. I've been researching all morning on how to use `alloc` with that flag enabled. I've gone down a few rabbit holes, such as `build-std`, but I've come up blank.

*Note*: I'm aware of the implications; this isn't a question of if I should or shouldn't, only a question of how to enable `no_global_oom_handling`?

Does anyone know how actually to enable this feature? I'm surprised it's not documented everywhere, even its tracking issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to pass a [`--cfg`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustc/command-line-arguments.html#--cfg-configure-the-compilation-environment) option. Either as arguments if using `rustc` directly, or in a `RUSTFLAGS` [environment variable](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/environment-variables.html) or `build.rustflags` [configuration option](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/config.html) in `.cargo/config.toml` when using Cargo.

An example (including [`build-std`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/unstable.html#build-std)):

```bash
RUSTFLAGS="--cfg no_global_oom_handling" cargo +nightly run -Z build-std
```

See also: [How to set cfg options to compile conditionally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57338478/how-to-set-cfg-options-to-compile-conditionally)

Comment: I think they'll still need `-Zbuild-std` for this to work

Comment: @PitaJ you're almost definitely right, I've added that to the example command

Comment: So far, I've adopted the `.cargo/config.toml` route. I've then tried `cargo +nightly build -Z build-std=core,alloc --target x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu`. It now builds, but when testing, I can still use items from `alloc` marked with `#[cfg(not(no_global_oom_handling))]`. Perhaps Rust is still seeing the `extern crate alloc` to resolve to the prebuilt one? It's causing me a lot of trouble.

Comment: It seems that my use case is still not supported; while the answer doesn't work as-is, it's good enough for anyone who stumbles across this in the future.

Answer (score 0):

For `vscode` you can edit the `settings.json` and edit an associated configuration setting. Here the key is the `cfg` name, such as `"feature"`, while the value is a string such as, `"ssr"` as follows:

```
"rust-analyzer.cargo.cfgs": {
   "config_name": "config_setting",
   ...
}
```

for example,

```
"rust-analyzer.cargo.cfgs": {
   "feature": "ssr"
}
```

(not sure how to set multiple values such as multiple features this way, however and no time to investigate further).